# Loop through selected slides and delete namned shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a "sticker" macro for PowerPoint. In short terms I have a button that marks selected slides with a shape that says "Done". This macro is working. However, I also need a macro that deletes the done-sticker on selected slides. What I have right now manages to delete the shape if only one slide is selected. I am very new to VBA in PowerPoint.

**Add sticker macro (that works):**

```
Sub StickerDone()

Dim StickerText As String
Dim sld As Slide

StickerText = "Done"

Dim shp As Shape

For Each sld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange

'Create shape with Specified Dimensions and Slide Position
    Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=0 * 28.3464567, Top:=0 * 28.3464567, Width:=80, Height:=26.6)

'FORMAT SHAPE
    'Shape Name
        shp.Name = "StickerDone"

    'No Shape Border
        shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse

    'Shape Fill Color
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(56, 87, 35)

    'Shape Text Color
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    'Text inside Shape
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = StickerText

    'Center Align Text
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter

    'Vertically Align Text to Middle
        shp.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle

    'Adjust Font Size
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14

    'Adjust Font Style
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Corbel"

    'Rotation
        shp.Rotation = 0

Next sld

End Sub
```

**Delete sticker macro (that does not work):**

```
Sub StickerDelete()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sld As Slide

    For Each sld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Name Like "StickerDone" Then

                shp.Select
                shp.Delete

            End If

        Next shp

    Next sld

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Your delete macro works fine when multiple slides are selected.  I see no reason to iterate through the slides twice.   The answer Sam gave you will only work on slides selected, just like yours.  I tested your macro and other than not needing to select the shape, it worked fine.  Glad you got a solution, just not sure yours wasn't one too.

Comment: Strange, for me it did not work. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting objects you are iterating over is generally a bad idea. Add them to an array and delete them after your (inner) loop is done.

Try this:

```
Sub StickerDelete()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sld As Slide

    ReDim ShapesToDelete(0)
    Dim ShapeCount

    For Each sld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Name Like "StickerDone" Then

                'shp.Select
                'shp.Delete
                ShapeCount = ShapeCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve ShapesToDelete(0 To ShapeCount)
                Set ShapesToDelete(ShapeCount) = shp

            End If

        Next shp

    Next sld

    For i = 1 To ShapeCount
        ShapesToDelete(i).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hm, could you please elaborate? I am not so skilled in PowerPoint VBA.